# Was there and if so what was a northern silk road route from Khazaria to China?

Tags: middle-ages, china, persia, steppe-nomads, tang-dynasty

From the reading I had done in various sources through the years, I understood that possible silk road routes from Khazaria to China were:

- **Northern:** *Atil - Tashkent - Dunhuang - Chang'an*
- **Central:** Persia, India and Himalaya
- **Southern:** Persia, India and Burma

Was there and if so what was a northern silk road route from Khazaria to China (what were the main cities and towns)?
I am having hard time finding such towns and cities in maps.

Comment: Please tell us what sources you have looked at.

Comment: I think it's a waste of time because I shouldn't try to dump here any source I went through through the years, let along didn't internalize if it was some webpage in some webpage from Google maps; it was most likely encyclopedias and various maps from Google maps.

Comment: @JustaHumbleAsker, as part of our community rules, questions that have been asked that make statements that imply sources are involved in the question must be accompanied by the source.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is in violation of our code of conduct.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about a geographical road.

The silk roads went through the country you mentionned in your North, central and South examples. They put in common trade a lot of actors, not only Persia and China or whoever. Southern Europe (Byzantine Empire, Italian harbours) Arab world and Persia were milestones as well as partners of the trade with China, India and even the Moluques Islands.

In this big commercial network, Khazars were partners and milestones as well. They opened an efficient road to Eastern and Central Europe, and they had a big piece of land under control which meant they had some resources for the silk roads such as furs.

Obviously from the map, the roads that connected Khazars were in Central Asia (Tashkent) and in Persia.